# How to capture Workflow email alerts under activity history with date and time

Tags: apex, workflow, email-alert

I am sending a reminder email through workflow email alert. I need to capture those email alerts under Activity history

[image]

Ex: I have set an email alert to trigger 15 days before today. Assume email triggered on 15th Aug at 02:30 PM. I need to capture that email alerts under Activity history with date and time. If we can capture workflow email alerts under the Activity history we can capture the date and time also I believe.

Comment: Check these links 1 - https://jenwlee.wordpress.com/2017/07/11/log-an-email-sent-via-email-alert-to-the-activity-history/     2 - https://medium.com/@brilligence/salesforce-recording-activity-history-on-workflow-email-alerts-8ae227fa8cee

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using Workflow rules to trigger email alerts, activities are not automatically logged when the email is sent.

So to do this, have the Workflow trigger a task (in addition to the email alert that is sent). You can assign the task to the record owner, creator, a certain role, or a specific user. You can also set the task to "Completed" so it will just be used for tracking purposes.

Once the Workflow is triggered, the email will be sent and a completed activity will be logged on that particular record simultaneously.

You can also vote the idea here: [Workflow email alerts to contacts should be recordable as activity history](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroKAAS)

[Log an activity when using Workflow Rules to send email alerts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005058&type=1)

Comment: Hi Sharma, I'm really sorry that my question was wrong. Can you Please refer updated question again and help me?. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Frank check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way to do this. Don't want to assign a task to someone. Email alerts should automatically capture like other emails which we sent through Send Email Button or replies to those emails.

Comment: @Frank I don't think there is any other option. Unless you want to use code. As task status is completed so it will not be a issue.

Comment: So what should I give the Due date for the task to Capture after immediate reminder email trigger?

Comment: @Frank it will be today.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing that it’s one of the most popular items on the idea exchange. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroKAAS

And we had already made a solution for it. So we packaged it up for free. It might be worth mentioning on your blog if you think it’s a better solution:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMWT8UAP
https://gravitylab.nz/send-email-alerts-and-log-the-email/

I hope it helps.